# Is this a Hadamard outer product?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

A Hadamard outer product is a level-2 BLAS operation i.e., $O(n^2)$ in which this product represented by product of two vectors $x$ and $y$ respectively of length $m$ and $n$ such that $xy^{\intercal}$ produces an $m\times n$ matrix.

I encountered a problem where I have an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and I want multiply it by a vector $$\mathbf{c}=\begin{bmatrix}c_1&c_2&\cdots& c_n\end{bmatrix}$$ such that the $j^{\text{th}}$ column of $A$ is multiplied by the $j^{\text{th}}$ entry of $c$.

I managed to successfully implement it on MATLAB and the operation can be described as $A(:,j).*c^{\intercal}(j)$ for $j=1,2,\cdots n$ where .* represents the element-wise product.

My simply question is can this be considered a Hadamard outer product? My main doubt is that the Hadamard outer product is between two vectors while in my case I have a "row-vector of column vectors (i.e.,matrix)" and a vector.

I wish to clarify something regarding the vector $c$ . I defined it as a row vector but on MATLAB the command $\mathsf{c(j)}$ outputs the vector $c$ as a column vector and that's why I transpose it.

Comment: This is a matrix multiplication of $A$ by the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(c)$.

Comment: Hello, I think what you described would be a level-3 BLAS (matrix matrix operation) while I intended to refer to the level-2 BLAS operation (matrix-vector) @user1551